# Government Oversight Committee

Tags: united-states, congress, intelligence-service

How is a committee, for example, the [House Intelligence Committee](http://intelligence.house.gov/) formed, how do the people that oversee the intelligence agencies get selected?

Answer (score 6):

Congressional committee assignments are decided by the party leadership in the chamber of Congress where the committee resides.  This is done at the start of each session of congress and unless a seat opens up through someone stepping down, is reassigned to another committee, retirement, death, or impeachment the committees remain the same until the next Congress is seated.  At the start of each session each representative or senator can request a position on a specific committee though the leadership is not required to abide the requests.  Each party is allotted seats on the committees based on the number of seats it holds in the chamber where the party resides.  The chairman of the committee is determined by the leader of the party with the most seats on the committee.

Wikipedia has a more in-depth write up of the [United States Congressional Committee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_committee)

Comment: One modification: People can step down from committees, and party leadership can remove people from a committee assignment also.   I'd have to look up the rules to get a reference, but I'm sure I've seen it happen.

Comment: @Indigochild - Good point they could also be moved from one committee to another opening up a seat on their original committee.  The leadership can ask them to step down from the committee but if they refuse to get them off the committee would require impeachment.  But if you refuse to step down from a committee do not ever expect another committee assignment.

Comment: Or worse - Don't expect party funds for the next round of elections.

Answer (score 2):

The House Intelligence Committee has particular requirements that do not apply to other House committees and are not mentioned in the Wikipedia articles, *[United States congressional committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_congressional_committee)* and *[United States House Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_House_Permanent_Select_Committee_on_Intelligence)*. These are given in *[Rules of the House of Representatives](https://rules.house.gov/sites/democrats.rules.house.gov/files/HouseRulesManual116/rules_non_annotated.xml)*, Rule X 11(a), Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence.

> (1) The select committee shall be composed of not more than 22 Members, Delegates, or the Resident Commissioner, of whom not more than 13 may be from the same party. The select committee shall include at least one Member, Delegate, or the Resident Commissioner from each of the following committees:
>
> (A) the Committee on Appropriations;
> (B) the Committee on Armed Services;
> (C) the Committee on Foreign Affairs; and
> (D) the Committee on the Judiciary.
>
> (2) The Speaker and the Minority Leader shall be ex officio members of the select committee but shall have no vote in the select committee and may not be counted for purposes of determining a quorum thereof.

Presumably, the requirement for membership from the four named committees is to reduce the need to share classified information with the whole of those committees. The *ex officio* membership of the Speaker and the Minority Leader reduces the need to share classified information with other party members.